# Convert an array to a string, but separate elements with single quotes

Tags: php, arrays

Convert an array to a string, but separate elements with single quotes
I tried the method `Implode`

`implode(",", $array);`

But it generates a single string of the form `"value1, value2, value3"` , but I want it to be generated in the form `"'value1', 'value2', 'value3'"`, I hope they can help me

Comment: `implode("','", $array);`? The "glue" string doesn't need to be a single character. You'll only need to add the beginning end ending `'` yourself (`$string = "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'";`)

Comment: `$joined = "\"'".implode("','", $array)."'\"";`

Comment: @JaredFarrish It is possible for that string to send to a `select * from tabla where names in (?)` , And I send bindParam `(1, $names, PDO :: PARAM_STR);` ? I'm trying but it does not return anything , $names is return implode.

Comment: I think when you bind, you can bind an array into the `IN()`, but I don't do parametized queries directly very often. This, though, would query: `select * from tabla where names in ("'".implode("','", $array)."'")` Note I removed the `""` around the list of array items. You would need to do a `FIND_IN_SET("\"'".implode("','", $array)."'\"")` instead (which is slow and totally unnecessary here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ' ' around every element in the array, then implode.

```
foreach($array as $item){
  $item = "'".$array."'";
  $array[] = $item;
}

implode(",", $array);
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish It is possible for that string to send to a `select * from tabla where names in (?)` , And I send bindParam `(1, $names, PDO :: PARAM_STR);` ? I'm trying but it does not return anything , $names is return implode.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('value2','value3','value4');

$sarray = "'".implode("', '",$array)."'";
```